# What "finitely generated" vector space means?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please help me understand the concept of "finitely generated" vector space, I am having a hard time visualizing and understanding it..

Thanks :)

Comment: A finitely generated vector space means you only need a finite number of elements to generate the vector space using linear combinations. E.g. For ${\bf R}^2$ you only need $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ to generate all of ${\bf R}^2$.

Comment: Also often called "finite-dimensional." "Finitely generated" is usually used when talking about the more general notion of module.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing does it as an example and some intuition. First of all: *What is a vector space?*

I like to think of it as a space $(V,+,\cdot)$ of objects $v \in V$ that can be added with each other ($v+u \in V$) and scaled (i.e. scalar multiplicated $\lambda \cdot v=\lambda v \in V$) by some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ (let's just assume we have a real vector space).

If you now think of $\mathbb R ^3$ as a vector space, which describes our real world, you can reach every point in space by using 3 different directions (up/down left/right back/forth) and add and scale them approriately.

For instance pick  $ \space\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\3\\-2\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb R ^3$. Now if you pick the three vectors $\space\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\\0\end{array}\right), \space\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\end{array}\right),\space\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)$, you can obtain your first vector by summing and scaling i.e:

$$ 1 \cdot \space\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\\0\end{array}\right)+ 3 \cdot\space\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\end{array}\right)+ (-2)\cdot\space\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)=\space\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\3\\-2\end{array}\right)$$

So what have we done? We picked a vector in our vector space and were able to express it in terms of *finitely many vectors* in our vector space only requiring $(+,\cdot)$. If one wants to be rigorous (which I urgue you to try!) one should abstract this idea to general definitions of:

- **Basis** of a vector space
- the **span**
- **linear indipendence**
- the **dimension** of a vector space

All these definitions are very important (look them up if you don't know them or revisit them otherwise) and indispensable for understanding what a vector space is. You can look them up and try to match them with the example I just gave as a motivation *why* one defines things as they are defined. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: I'm not necessarily familiar with the english terminology but shouldn't it be "the span of a subset of $V$"? Because the span of a subset of a vector space is by definition the set of all linear combinations of elements of this subset, i.e. the vector space generated by the subset. And it is quite tautologic to say the span of a vector space since a vector space is "by definition" the set of all linear combinations of elements of $V$.
It is probably not at the level of the OP, but the formal defintion of a vector space is a $\mathbb{F}$-module where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, no?

Comment: Yeah you are right, that's kinda redundant. I'll edit it. And yes, that's the most general definition of a vector space I know too.